# using the loop on a page

Tags: loop

I'm trying to display the excerpt of the most recent post and just the titles of the 4 previous posts before that at the top of a page and display the content of the page below. I have a solution that's close and works but not sure if I need to reset query and how to get excerpt on most recent post and title on 4 previous. [Here's the page with post titles at top (B's recommended articles)](http://www.rabbib.com/bs-recs/) and the content (that can be edited) of the page is underneath. Here's the code http://pastebin.com/41x30Uyb

Answer (score 0):

To use template tags within a foreach loop outputting the results of `get_posts`, use the function [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to populate the global `$post` with the data it needs. To style the first post differently, use a counter to keep track of which post you're outputting. After finishing output, use [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) to restore the `$post` global. `wp_reset_query` is only necessary if you modify the global `$wp_query`.

```
$posts = get_posts( 'category=124&numberposts=5' );
$count = 1;
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    if( 1 == $count ){
        the_title();
    } else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
    $count++;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit. Changed the excerpt and title positions (I wanted the most recent as excerpt then the previous 4 as titles) I also added a title link above the excerpt and date function after each title - thank you. You can see it here http://www.rabbib.com/bs-recs/